# Where is Max hidden in Monkey Island 2?

Tags: monkey-island-2-lechucks-revenge

An ongoing in-joke in the SCUMM-based LucasArts adventure games was hiding Max (from the Sam and Max comic, then later *Sam and Max Hit the Road*) in the scenery. He was never (or almost never) something you could interact with, just a little easter egg.

Does anyone know where (if) he's hidden in Monkey Island 2, and whether or not his hidden visage is visible in the new Special Edition's graphics as well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Costumes of Sam & Max can be found in the [Costume Shop](http://miwiki.net/The_Costume_Shop):

[image]

However, it seems that in the new version, they are replaced by a purple tentacle (from day of the tentacle), because LucasArts doesn't own the rights for Sam & Max anymore ([forum source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/991338-monkey-island-2-special-edition-lechucks-revenge/55496676), for what it's worth). Apparently it was the same in the special edition of the first episode as well.

Comment: What is the "new" version?